# Bootstrap popover doesn't appear the first time on hover event using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

The appropriate bits of what I tried are here:

```
$(".popovers").mouseover( function()
{
    //var mainTableBody = document.getElementById("subCriteriaTableBody");
    var tableRows = document.getElementsByClassName("popoversBlock");
    var i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) 
    {
        var labelList = tableRows[i].getElementsByTagName("label");             
        var tdList = tableRows[i].getElementsByClassName("popovers");               
        for (j = 0; j < labelList.length; j++) 
        {
            if(labelList[j].parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex == tdList[j].parentElement.rowIndex) 
            {   
                attName = $(this).text();   
                var attributeName = attName.slice(0, -1);   
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/diganta/getPopoverValueReassignTaskOfUser.do?attributeName='+attributeName,  
                    type:'post',  
                    dataType: 'json',  
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('.popovers').attr('data-content', data.PopoverValue); 
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Failed! Reason: "+ thrownError);
                    }
                });
                break;
            } 
            else 
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I mouse hover, I see the request get made, but doesn't populate the popover. I don't even see JSP page for the popover first time but second time it's ok get added to the DOM.

Please help me .... 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call

```
$('.popovers').attr('data-content', data.PopoverValue).popover('show');
```

to show the `Popover`

Hope it will solve your problem...

**Edit**

```
$('#your_lable_id').attr('data-content', data.PopoverValue).popover('show');
```

Comment: I have totally 4 popovers with this class .popovers, I have added the .popover('show') but it will show all of the popovers.

Comment: On what kind of  UI use those 4 popovers?

Comment: I have used html label tag

Comment: just set id for all label and call popover on that ... i am editing the answer.... see the edited answer ..

Answer (score 1):

If the problem appears at the first time only and it works afterwards, you are probably missing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ...
});
```

Another advice, [quoting W3C page](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_popover.asp):

> Popovers are not CSS-only plugins, and must therefore be initialized with jQuery: select the specified element and call the popover() method.

Comment: and you are missing the last closing bracket `)`. ;D